# sqlalchemy association table with three foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am learning about association objects in sqlalchemy and about table relationships in general.  I have an application where users apply tags to articles.  To capture this, I have created an association table with three foreign keys.  I am beginning to understand that you never do this, as an association can only have a left and a right (ie associate two tables).  However, the idea still seems good to me.  I would use this association object to look up what articles a user tagged with a given tag.  What am I not understanding?

```
class UsersAppliedTags(alchemyDB.Model):
    '''
        a association object to handle the tags which a user applies to other people's entries
    '''
    __tablename__ = 'users_applied_tags'
    id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, primary_key = True)
    tag_id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, alchemyDB.ForeignKey('tagTable.id'))
    entry_id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, alchemyDB.ForeignKey('entries.id'))
    user_id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, alchemyDB.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

Comment: I have this identical problem and this is a very "normal" form of relationship between entities in a database.  One thing though is that your users_applied_tags table doesn't need a distinct primary key; the combination of tag_id, entry_id, and user_id is the primary key for the table so you can just add "primary_key=True " to all of those and get rid of the id column.